# How to set default values into an Array Field Django?

Tags: python, arrays, django, field, default

I would like to know how to set default values into a Django Array Field Model.

I have a TextChoices model named "GameType" :

```
 class GameType(models.TextChoices):
    '''
    Enumeration of all different game types
    '''
    EVIL = 'evil', 'evil'
    SOLOCOOP = 'solo', 'solo'
    MULTI = 'multi', 'multi'
```

And in my Item model, I can choose in each mode my item is available. Then I have these lines :

```
      game_types = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(
            default=GameType.SOLOCOOP,
            max_length=40,
            choices=GameType.choices
        ), default=default_item_game_types, null=False, blank=False)
```

Two things :

1. The first default key "GameType.SOLOCOOP" doesn't work
2. The default list doesn't work too

Here is my "default_item_game_types" function :

```
def default_item_game_types():
    '''Default callable to avoid errors
    '''
    return list(GameType)
```

And in my CMS, I don't have my default values :

[Screenshot of my Game types field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db8vB.png)

I tried many things and searched many solutions but nothing matched in my case.

Is there any response to fix my issues ?

Thanks for your time

Regards,

Steven

Answer (score 0):

1: You need to set it like

```
self.SOLOCOOP = 'solo'
```

Can do this in a custom method or **init** if you know the defaults for it, that would be much easier than calling the custom method.

2:The default values are based on the Charfield as it is an Array of fields in some sense.

EDITED:

Just do the str_value then or better just do the key value for solar as you're already using it as choices in the parameter below.

Comment: In text choices, we have the key "solo" and the text display when this text choice is called "Solo", then i can't set it like "self.SOLOCOOP = 'solo'"

And I need my custom method because I use it in another classes :(

Comment: GameType.choices['solo'] or GameType.choices.solo

Comment: As that is the actual key